# Specifying tab delimiters etc from commandline in java

Tags: java

I have this code.. which takes in the string and splits it based on delimiter.
For example:

```
void splitLine(String line, String delimiter){

    String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);

}
```

Now.. I am taking this "delimiter" from command line..

```
options.addOption("d", "delimiter", true, "default delim is ,");
```

and later getting this option as:

```
delim = cmd.getOptionValue("d");
```

And then I pass this delim to the function..

But how do i specify "tab" in the command line.. in order to make this code work?
Lets say I run this code with

```
java -jar foo.jar -d ~ //if i want to split the line by "~"
```

Comment: Maybe provide the delimiter as quoted in a string, and allow an escape character like:  -d "~"   or - d "\t" for tab - standard escape sequences, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string literal in Java for tab is `\t`. From the Oracle documentation:

> The Java programming language also supports a few special escape
>   sequences for `char` and `String` literals: `\b` (backspace), `\t` (tab), `\n`
>   (line feed), `\f` (form feed), `\r` (carriage return), `\"` (double quote),
>   `\'` (single quote), and `\\` (backslash).